# Meteor iOS and Android open url in device's browser

Tags: android, ios, meteor

I have looks tirelessly for an easy solution to this problem but couldn't find one. How do you open a link to the device's browser from your Meteor mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```

target: The target in which to load the URL, an optional parameter that defaults to _self. (String)

_self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.

_blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.

_system: Opens in the system's web browser.

source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser